# VSCode how to disable cmd+click jump definition's pop up?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts, key-bindings

Wrote a component in react, and use it in another place.

When I `command+click` to jump to the component definition it always show a confusing scrollbar.

How to disable it, and I just want to jump to it meta source file definition.

[image: vscode]

Comment: What's your  `editor.multiCursorModifier` setting?

Comment: "editor.multiCursorModifier": "alt"

Answer (score -1):

Instead of *"go to definition"* , you might want to use *"go to implementation"* command.

Default keybinding is **ctrl+F12**

Answer (score -1):

It's vscode's bug about js arrow function.

Next release will fix it probably.

[vscode issue1](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/54367)

[vscode issue2](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/51918)